# Why does ergodicity fail?

Tags: lie-groups, abelian-groups, ergodic-theory, haar-measure, maximal-subgroup

Apparently the following is not ergodic, and a very sketchy argument is given, so I was hoping someone here would be able to explain/give a better argument.

Suppose $G$ is a compact connected non-abelian Lie group with Haar measure $m$ and fix $h\in G$. Let $X$ be a bounded metric space and $F:X\to X$ ergodic. Let $F_h:X\times G\to X\times G$ be given by $F_h(x,g)=(Fx,gh)$.

Apparently this is not ergodic. The argument I am referring to says: $H=\langle h\rangle$ is abelian, hence is a proper subspace of $G$. It follows that $m(H)=0$. (This part is clear).

$H$ is at most a maximal torus. In particular, the ergodic components have measure zero and ergodicity fails.

The part which confuses me is the previous sentence. Could anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: Suppose some union of cosets $B := \cup_\alpha g_\alpha H$ has positive measure less than 1. Then $F_h^{-1}(X\times B) = F^{-1}X \times Bh^{-1} = X\times B$, which will prove non-ergodicity.